# Prove ALL$_{\text{TM}}$ is undecidable reduction problem

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability

Given ALL$_{\text{TM}}$ = { < M > | where M is a TM and L(M) = $Σ^*$ } show this is undecidable. I'm also told not to use Rice's theorem. I'm having difficulties with reduction type problems. How would you do a proof for this using a reduction of A$_{\text{TM}}$? Any pointers to resources are much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving ALLTM complement not recognizable](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/proving-alltm-complement-not-recognizable)

Comment: What searching have you done?  There are *lots* of worked examples here (see the [tag:reductions] tag), and in standard textbooks.  If you want help understanding how to do reductions, I suggest reading standard references -- there would be little point in repeating that material.  As for your specific exercise, I don't know whether anyone will be interested in doing the exercise for you.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to show ALL$_{TM}$ is undecidable by Rice's theorem.

Where ALL$_{TM}$ = {<M>, M is a TM and L(M) = $\Sigma^*$}

Take two TMs M$_1$ and M$_2$ where L(M$_1$) = L(M$_2$).

Because both recognize the same language,

- if $<M_1>$ $\in$ ALL$_{TM}$ then $<M_2>$ is too.
- if $<M_1>$ $\notin$ ALL$_{TM}$ then $<M_2>$ isn't as well.

So they either both have descriptions in ALL$_{TM}$, or none of them.

It is non-trivial:

- There trivially exists a TM M$_1$ that accepts on all inputs $w \in$ $\Sigma^*$.
- There trivially exists a TM M$_2$ that recognizes $L(M_2) =  \{ab\}$,
  which is clearly not in $\textit{ALL}_{TM}$

Now, by Rice's theorem, it is proven that ALL$_{TM}$ is undecidable.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce from $H_{TM}$:

For input $<M,w>$ return (the encoding) for a machine $M_ {M,w}$ such that on input $x$:

1. Simulate $M(w)$
2. $Accept$

It’s easy to show
$M_{M,w} \in ALL_{TM} \leftrightarrow <M,w>\in H_{TM}$